# Загрузка файла на сервер средствами PHP

Tags: php, веб-сервер, unix

Сразу перейду к сути вопроса.
Мне необходимо скачать файл с сервера A на свой сервер B, кажется всё просто, считываем файл средствами PHP и сохраняем данные на свой сервер.

Файл необходимо скачивать по запросу пользователя (пусть для примера это будет кнопка "сохранить на сервере"), исходя из этого - проблема следующая, PHP не дает "новое" соединение, пока не закроется старое. Соответственно, файл размером в 1 GB будет загружаться с сервера А на наш сервер 10 минут (если убрать таймаут, 10 минут для примера), от этого вся система не будет доступна, пока PHP не скачает файл и не закроет старое соединение. Можно ли обойти данную проблему и скачивать файл средствами PHP с сервера на сервера и во время скачивания давать пользователю "доступ" к скрипту?

Comment: Может я не так понял, но возможно [ignore_user_abort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort) поможет

Comment: если это веб-сайт и скрипт запущен всё время, то пользователь не сможет повторно получить ответ сервера, пока не скрипт не прекратит предыдущую задачу.

Comment: Почему бы работу по загрузке не дать другому скрипту.... Вообще есть очереди а-ля rabbitMQ когда нужно что-то сделать, но пользователю не нужно это сидеть и ждать.